# Angular 4/5 change of language depending on the browser language

Tags: javascript, internationalization, angular5

I make simple SPA in Angular 5 with to languages: base (polish) and additional (english). I would like to detect browser language and if is not polish load english version of app.
I tried to made it by changing dinamically base href:

my index.html

```
  <base href="/">
  <script>
    (function() {
      if (navigator.language !== 'pl') {
        window['_app_base'] = '/en';
      }
    })();
  </script>
```

and app.module.ts:

```
providers: [
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: window['_app_base'] || '/' }
  ],
```

It change base href but despite the href is "myapp.pl/en" it load base langugae - polish and I must refresh page to load english version of page.
It is possible to make it in Angular?

Comment: Show how you're setting the language.

Comment: Firstly I create files using: "$ ng xi18n --output-path src/locale" and then I made copy of .xlf filte to english version.  At the end I build base version using "npm run build" and english using "for lang in en; do ng build --output-path=dist/$lang --aot -prod --bh /$lang/ --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.$lang.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=$lang; done" and upload it the server